# error on ajax getting image from folder

Tags: php, jquery, json

PHP:

```
<?php

class GetProductImage{

    public function __construct() {
      echo json_encode("test");
    }

$GetProductImage = new GetProductImage();

?>
```

The AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "class/json-gallery-data.php",
    context: $("#contentWrapper-body"),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        folder : this.path,
    },
    success:function(d)
    {
        console.log(d);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        console.log('jqXHR:');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log('textStatus:');
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('errorThrown:');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

These are the 2 files I use to get all my images from the folder, but somehow I got this error. It didn't happen before, I dont know what was it.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:4)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

What problem did I have? Can anyone point out my problem and help me with it?

Comment: you have a `echo $dir;` before your `echo json_encode($directoryfiles);`, which will result in invalid json (since you have `dataType: "json"`)

Comment: i removed and still having same problem , yeah i notice it as well.

Comment: Have you opened `class/json-gallery-data.php` directly (you might need to change `$_POST["folder"];` to `$_GET["folder"];` && `class/json-gallery-data.php?folder=VaildFolderName` for testing) and see what the page outputs?

Comment: i did have a response text object which , show me my main html text. do that mean something ?

Comment: @deecheok You really should post what actual response you are getting. By the way with my almost-zero knowledge of PHP output of `json_encode("test")` will not be JSON according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. Please make sure to verify your code actually represents your problem and verify all error messages align with code.

Comment: There's a brace missing in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

That means your JSON file is returning HTML instead of JSON. This is most likely being caused either by a PHP error being printed, or by a redirect happening. Try changing `dataType: json` to `dataType: text/html` to see exactly what is being returned instead of a JSON error message and then act according to what the error is.

Comment: i change to text/html and i got this No conversion from text to text/html

Comment: @deecheok Hmm, maybe `text/plain` then?

Comment: same as well No conversion from text to text/plain

Answer (score 0):

Error means response browser is getting is not valid JSON. There are many reasons - returning HTML instead of JSON, returning error text or simply dumping extra unrelated text to output.

You are outputting extra text in addition to your JSON - remove `echo $dir` and looks like only JSON response will be there:

```
$dir = "../../../img/brand-product/".$folder."/";
echo $dir;
```

To confirm - look at the response in browser's developer tools or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: i got response text object which from my main html text.

Comment: You should edit your post to provide [MCVE] and details of your investigation. Clearly since you've already looked at the response in Fiddler you know what is returned - posting that would let someone answer your question.

Comment: i did i change all my php code to echo json_encode("text") , i still got the same problem.

Comment: i am using it on single page application , i think it maybe the context problem.

Comment: @deecheok please read on how to edit post - http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing and *edit your question* with details of your investigation and proper [MCVE].

Comment: i edited i think is the simple as it can be , i am using the this code and still have the same problem.